# Audio tags inside Ember each loop

Tags: ember.js, html5-audio

In an Ember application (Ember v3.13) I tried to iterate through an array of audio URLs, using an each loop in a template, and generate an audio tag for each...

I get the following error:

```
Assertion Failed: fullName must be a proper full name
```

The audio tag works fine outside of the each loop.

Wondering if anybody has seen this before or know what it means or if there’s a workaround?

This is the code in question:

```
{{#each audioURLS as |audio|}}
  <li>
    <audio controls preload="none" src={{audio}}>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: can you add the template code where you iterate over the array?

Comment: @stevenelberger Sure thing!

Comment: I notice that if I change it to a video tag I have no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different variable name. The introduction of angle bracket component invocation has caused problems with code that tries to invoke a component while passing in a variable with the same name:

```
{{#each audioURLS as |src|}}
  <li>
    <audio controls preload="none" src={{src}}>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I was just posting my own answer to the same effect and you must have been at the same time. Thanks, Steven!

Comment: @GordonIsnor Haha I see we were only minutes apart. Glad it works now! :)

Comment: I thought there is a template linting rule that should caught such issues. Do you have ember-cli-template-lint installed and hasn't it returned any error?

Answer (score 0):

I see what the problem was now. It was mentioned in this issue:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/17219

I had audio as the block param and was then trying to invoke the HTML5 audio tag and it caused a collision.

It’s a shame the error message was so completely vague, it often seems to be the case with Ember.

Updated my code from this:

```
{{#each audioURLS as |audio|}}
  <li>
    <audio controls preload="none" src={{audio}}>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

to this:

```
{{#each audioURLS as |a|}}
  <li>
    <audio controls preload="none" src={{a}}>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

And then it worked just fine.